# how to create a local server with dynamic redirect

Tags: php, html, http, url, tel

I would like to reproduce what has successfully done this guy here : https://www.labnol.org/internet/google-sheets-phone-numbers/

Indeed, since it is not possible to make callable hyperlink in Google Spreadsheets, he has set up a tool designed to redirect a classic http: hyperlink to a tel: hyperlink that any phone can understand

=HYPERLINK("https://ctrlq.org/call/"&A1; "Call +1 (555) 555-5555"

A1 value being for example "1-555-555-5555"

this makes a request to "https://ctrlq.org/call/1-555-555-5555" and returns "tel://1-555-555-5555"

Now I would like to create a local server on my iPhone able to reproduce this, but even without an internet connection.
I won't have any trouble about how to make this server, but I don't know where to start to create that redirect.

I would also like to keep the structure of the call request in order to maybe customize it later: "http://mywebsite.com/call/phone_number_international_format"

PHP maybe ? I do not know any PHP but if someone can give some strong tips I am sure I will find the way myself, I just don't know how to start. Complete solution will be provided at the end !

Comment: you wont have any trouble setting up a local php server on a IPhone? And why do you want to do this? Are you using google sheets offline

Comment: yes I do use GS offline, but the first goal here is to reproduce what "https://ctrlq.org/call/" does